# Python script to call an ABAP functional module to dump data in Hana table?

Tags: python-2.7, abap, hana, pyrfc

I need to connect to an ABAP Functional module using python to extract data from a table and dump it into another HANA table .How to call the RFC using pyrfc  module ? what is the syntax ? I dont find clear explanation in any forum .

Comment: It should be a simple python script which connects to ABAP function module and gets data directly into HANA system using looping logic

Comment: The examples on the github page for pyrfc seem pretty complete, what is not working?

Comment: Thanks Gert i followed the pyrfc documentation , i had some problems with my requirements . The ABAP call accepts only dictionary as input , so i converted my input to dictionary and im passing it . Now it works.